# Count parent directory in hadoop

Tags: hadoop

Can anyone help me out how to count only parent directory in hadoop?
 In backupDataHistory I have two directory dir1 and and dir2.
 Dir1 and Dir2 have more directories and files.
For me I need to count only directory which is in `/backupDataHistory` i.e only two namely dir1 and dir2
I am using this code:

```
 fs = FileSystem.get(getHBaseAdmin().getConfiguration());
 Path path = new Path("/backupDataHistroy");
 RemoteIterator<LocatedFileStatus> ri = fs.listFiles(path, false);
 while (ri.hasNext()) count++
```

This gives me zero count, If value for recurrisve is true gives me count 15.
 I have two directory in `backupDataHistory`. And I need only this two directory.
When I run `hadoop fs -ls /backupDataHistory` It shows 2 directory
When I run command `hadoop fs -count /backupDataHistory`, It is shows 15 Directory, 14 Files and byte size.

Comment: If you're including code, please edit it into the question and format it with code blocks.

Comment: Finally I am using ProcessBuilder to solve this problem , Still waiting answer for this :) How to do with Hadoop API